# Retrieve 2nd element of Association List c#

Tags: c#

in Lisp

```
    (setq listOfMembers  '(
             ("SUPERMAN" "KRYPTO" )
             ("BATMAN" "ROBIN"    )
             ("JOKER" "HARLEY"    )
             ("MIGHTY MAN" "YUCK" )
                                     )

(cadr (assoc "BATMAN" listOfMembers))
returns
"ROBIN"
```

retrieves 2nd element of a nested list.

How does one go about doing this in C#?

**EDIT: I ended up using Dictonaries**

```
Dictionary<string, string[]> and Dictionary<string, string>
```

Thank you all

Comment: you want to look for `Dictionary<string, string>` [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Nested list or Dictionary(Key,Value pair)?

Comment: Best option: `List<SuperHero>`

Comment: So there are Class, Dictionary & Tuple, I'm going to try all three to see which one is easiest to absorb, a friend also told me to look into SQL. I'll keep you guys posted. Thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know LISP. I would go with:

```
Dictionary <string, string> heroes = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "SUPERMAN", "KRYPTO" }, { "BATMAN", "ROBIN" } };
var sidekick = heroes["BATMAN"];
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Looks very promising,  @Moerwald Thank you. Have to learn dictionary eventually.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly, you could use

```
List<Tuple<string,string>>
```

which is documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268536(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: or `List<List<string>>` or `string[][]` or `Dictionary<string, string>` or `List<SuperHero>` or whatever.

Comment: List<SuperHero> seems to be a good fit, that is using a Class right?

Answer (score 0):

As stated already in this thread you could define a List of Tuples. or you can create a Name Class to hold the names.  Such a class would contain the two strings. Here would be the simplest version of such as a class.

```
 public class Name
 {
    public String First;
    public String Last;
 }
```

Because List in C# encapsulates a dynamic array you can then access the second element directly by index.

To make the implementation closer to what you have shown in LISP.  You could use a C# Dictionary of type:

```
Dictionary<string,string>
```

where the key would be the first name or the first element in the Tuple.

Comment: does that mean use Name class to populate the dictionary elements? Thing ism, the data will be coming form an external text file. where the author will be updating the data from time to time, i guess SQL works the same way if i'm not mistaken

Comment: @pBe Whenever data is updated you just rebuild your list of Class Objects or Dictionary depending on your implementation. Because you index by the first string in the Tuple as opposed to a number, it would make more sense to go with a Dictionary.